# kerberos authentication in Windows 7

Tags: wcf, windows-7

I have to implement Kerberos-based Windows authentication in WCF. I am using Windows 7 Professional. I searched a lot but did not get any relevant article on this topic.

How can I implement Kerberos-based Windows authentication in WCF on Windows 7 Professional?

Comment: What have you tried? There's [plenty](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tiche/archive/2011/07/13/wcf-on-intranet-with-windows-authentication-kerberos-or-ntlm-part-1.aspx) [reading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295526/wcf-and-kerberos-authentication) [material](http://kjellsj.blogspot.nl/2007/01/wcf-security-wshttpbinding-with.html) out there. Please show some effort from your side, instead of offering a bounty so someone else will do the research for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this in one of my project written in C# .NET on windows side(worked on Windows 7 as well) to connect to UNIX server using Kerberos authentication to do required tasks. Your best bet would be use [Plink/Putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) SSL Client which has Kerberos authentication supported. 
You will need to setup your server infrastructure to generate key realm(Ticket Granting Server) and recognised by AS Authentication Server etc.