# WCF Says my settings require 'Anonymous' authentication - but I don't want them

Tags: .net, wcf, authentication

So [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026855/wcf-windows-authentication-security-settings-require-anonymous) has the exact same symptoms of my problem.

> Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.

However, I've removed the `mex` endpoint from my web config and I still get the same error. My web config looks like this:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="xxx.MessageHub.MessageHubService"
           behaviorConfiguration="default">
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding"
              contract="xxx.MessageHub.IMessageHubService" />
  </service>
</services>
    <behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
  </endpointBehaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="default">
                <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
                <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
      <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseWindowsGroups" />
            </behavior>

        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="credsOnly">
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"></transport>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="transport">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"></transport>
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I'm running the application with the IIS6 compatibility add on to IIS7 (because our prod servers run IIS6 - I get the same exception when deployed to the test server).

What settings do I need to fix to make this stuff work?

Comment: Did you try the other option in the question you posted? _Alternativelly you enable Anonymous access in IIS and in your web.config you make sure anonymous access is denied._

Comment: I'm not sure if that setup will work in our environment - though if I can't get this worked out it may be worth checking out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by following the steps found at this [msdn post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648505.aspx), slightly modified:

1. Right-click the Web.config file of the WCF service and then click **Edit WCF Configuration**.
2. In the Configuration Editor, in the Configuration section, select the **Bindings** folder.
3. In the Bindings section, choose **New Binding Configuration**.
4. In the Create a New Binding dialog box, select **wsHttpBinding**.
   Click OK.
5. Set the **Name** of the binding configuration to some logical and recognizable name; for example, **WsHttpEndpointBinding**.
6. Click the **Security** tab.
7. Set the **Mode** attribute to **Transport** by choosing this option from the drop-down menu.
8. Set the **TransportClientCredentialType** to **Ntlm** by choosing this option from the drop-down list.
9. In the **Configuration** section, select **WsHttpEndpoint**.
10. Set the BindingConfiguration attribute to **WsHttpEndpointBinding** by choosing this option from the drop-down list.
    This associates the binding configuration setting with the binding.
11. In the Configuration Editor, on the File menu, click Save.

And (as far as I know) this provides authentication using integrated authentication (but not Windows integrated).