# IIS Client Certificate Mapping Returns 500 When Anonymous Authentication Disabled

Tags: wcf, iis

I have a WCF client application hitting a WCF web service running under IIS 7.5 on Windows 2008 Server R2.  I have a "client" certificate on the client machine, and a "server" certificate on the server machine.  I have successfully configured IIS and the client app to use straight "1-way" SSL.  However, I am not able to get "2-way" SSL (SSL w/Client Certificate REQUIRED) to work.

I have taken the client certificate, exported as Base-64, formatted the resulting text string, and added that in as an entry under IIS Client Certificate Mapping on the IIS server.  I've tied this to a Windows user, and given that user access to the folder where the web service runs from. I have done all of this configuration at the site level under IIS Manager.

The problem shows up when I DISABLE anonymous authentication.  If I do this, then IIS gives me a return code of 500 and an accompanying error telling me I must enable anonymous authentication.  This is not what I want.  If I RE-ENABLE anonymous authentication, then any client using a valid client certificate is able to make the web service call.  I want to limit the ability to call the service only to those clients that present a client certificate that I have mapped to the Windows user.

Has anyone else come across this?

Thanks!

Brian

Comment: Could you add the error details which IIS gives when you get 500 ?

Comment: WebHost failed to process a request.
 ......
Exception: System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '?????????????????????' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation.  The exception message is: Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.. ---> System.NotSupportedException: Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.

Comment: The '?????' replace the actual name of the service.

Comment: Have you checked this answer out? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1026855/wcf-windows-authentication-security-settings-require-anonymous The settings mentioned there are located in your IIS hosts file which defaults to this location %systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc folder